# IDEA Intellij does not support Cucumber JVM World (Hooks) in Groovy

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy, cucumber

If I use `cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks.World` then tests are working fine. But I cannot open declaration in steps definition

```
World() {
        def world = new LucieWorld()
        world.metaClass.mixin Lucie
        world
    }
```

step definition:

```
Given(~/^User is (.+)$/) { def username ->
    login(username) //I cannot open declaration here
}
```

When I am in a step definition file (groovy), `Intellij` can't seem to see variables and methods defined in the cucumber "World" object `Lucie`. So don't get IDE support (auto-complete, etc) for those which is a bit annoying. How can I fix that?

I try to use `this.metaClass.mixin(Lucie)` in step definition, but I think, that this is not a good solution.